# Gremlin comparing two properties of a single node

Tags: gremlin

Given below mentioned dataset, how do I check

1. TotalPay of the employee where totalPay is variablePay + FixedPay
2. What percentage variable pay is to TotalPay
3. If totalPay is less than 100,000

```java
g.addV('employee').
  property(id,'employeeId_1').
  property('variablePay',20000.00).
  property('fixedPay',70000.00)
```

The query below doesn't seems to work.

```
g.V('employeeId_1').has('variablePay', lt('fixedPay')).hasNext()
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are wanting to do. Are you wanting to check while adding a second vertex?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I want to know if a vertex has two numeric properties, is it possible to do ordinary add / subtract / division / multiplication  / less than / greater than operation among those two properties. I may have used the confusing name for properties min / max. Another example i can think of is employee vertex is holding salary and bonus pay and we have to find total pay the employee or what percentage of salary bonus pay is etc....

Comment: The simple answer is yes but there is not a lot in your original question to work with. For example you can easily do `values(‘a’, ‘b’).sum()` where a and b are properties of a vertex.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence  I have updated my original post with few additional question. Your previous reply helped answering one of my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an area of Gremlin that is a bit confusing as today, predicates such as `lt` and `gt` can only take a literal value and not any sort of traversal such as `lt(values('fixedPay'))`.

You can work around this using a `where by` query that uses two `by` modulators:

```java
gremlin> g.V('employeeId_1').as('v').where(lt('v')).by('variablePay').by('fixedPay')

==>v[employeeId_1]
```

If we reverse the test, there is no result as expected.

```java
gremlin> g.V('employeeId_1').as('v').where(lt('v')).by('fixedPay').by('variablePay')
gremlin>
```